# Programmatically generate DDL statement for User Defined Data Type (UDDT)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tsqlt, system-tables, user-defined-data-types

I'm trying to add faking synonyms pointing to remote objects support([PR](https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/pull/48)) for [tSQLt](https://tsqlt.org).

To make it possible to mock/fake tables that have user defined system types in the table definitions, I need to generate the User Defined Data Type (UDDT) DDL statement.

I don't have too much experience with UDDTs, and what I can think of about very simple scenario if the UDDT just is as simple if it would be something like `CREATE TYPE dbo.SomeType FROM INT`, but I know that it can be much more complex.

So, the question is if anyone has some working solution already, ideally implemented using T-SQL via system objects. In the worst case, SQLCLR would be the only other option.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? I assume not the regular create as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: You could refer this :   
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1628/sql-server-user-defined-data-types-rules-and-defaults/

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Are you interested to use SQLCLR? Or SMO?

Comment: So you're trying to duplicate a UDT from one database to another, is that correct? You're looking to generate SQL from an existing UDT that you can execute against another DB?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: There are different kinds of User-Defined Types: User-Defined Table Types (UDTT), User-Defined Types (UDT; complex types implemented via SQLCLR), and User-Defined Data Types (UDDT; mainly synonyms of existing system types, but with size/precision and `NULL` / `NOT NULL` included). I updated the title, question, and tags to reflect that you are really asking about UDDTs, not UDTs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different kinds of User-Defined Types: User-Defined Table Types (UDTT), User-Defined Types (UDT; complex types implemented via SQLCLR), and User-Defined Data Types (UDDT; mainly synonyms of existing system types, but with size/precision and `NULL` / `NOT NULL` included).

You don't need to worry about UDTTs as they cannot be columns in tables.

You probably can't deal with UDTs, at least not right now, as that adds a lot of complexity since you would need to copy the assembly as well.

There is one main system catalog view: `sys.types`. The following should get you most, if not all, of what you need. `collation_name` does not appear to be usable, either by testing a simple `CREATE TYPE` as a test, or the documentation.

```sql
SELECT N'CREATE TYPE ' + QUOTENAME(sch.[name])
         + N'.' + QUOTENAME(typ.[name])
         + N' FROM ' + styp.[name]
         + CASE
             WHEN typ.[system_type_id] IN
                       (41, 42, 43, 106, 108, 165, 167, 173, 175, 231, 239)
               THEN N'('
                    + CASE
                        WHEN typ.[max_length] = -1 -- for: VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, VARBINARY
                          THEN N'MAX'
                        WHEN typ.[system_type_id] IN (165, 167, 173, 175)
                          -- VARBINARY, VARCHAR, BINARY, CHAR
                          THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), typ.[max_length])
                        WHEN typ.[system_type_id] IN (231, 239) -- NVARCHAR, NCHAR
                          THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), (typ.[max_length] / 2))
                        WHEN typ.[system_type_id] IN (41, 42, 43)
                          -- TIME, DATETIME2, DATETIMEOFFSET
                          THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), typ.[scale])
                        WHEN typ.[system_type_id] IN (106, 108) -- DECIMAL, NUMERIC
                          THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), typ.[precision]) 
                               + N', ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), typ.[scale])
                        END            
                    + N')'
             ELSE N''
           END
         + CASE typ.[is_nullable] WHEN 1 THEN N' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END
         + N';'
FROM   sys.types typ
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
        ON sch.[schema_id] = typ.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.types styp
        ON styp.[user_type_id] = typ.[system_type_id]
WHERE  typ.[is_user_defined] = 1
AND    typ.[is_assembly_type] = 0
AND    typ.[is_table_type] = 0;
```

**Rules**

*!! These have been deprecated for a long time and should not be used !!*

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-rule-transact-sql) for `CREATE RULE`

Rules can be found in: `sys.sql_modules` (which includes the `CREATE` statement in the `[definition]` field)

You will need to separately cycle through `sys.types` and, for any user-created types where `rule_object_id <> 0`, execute `EXEC sp_bindrule N'@rulename', N'@objectname';`.

**Defaults**

*!! These have been deprecated for a long time and should not be used !!*

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-default-transact-sql) for `CREATE DEFAULT`

Defaults can be found in: `sys.sql_modules` (which includes the `CREATE` statement in the `[definition]` field)

You will need to separately cycle through `sys.types` and, for any user-created types where `default_object_id <> 0`, execute `EXEC sp_bindefault N'@defaultname', N'@objectname';`.

Comment: what about defaults, rules?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev ok, added info for Rules and Defaults.  It is _highly_ unlikely that either are used, so I need to re-focus on stuff that I am behind on...if you need them, the info provided (below the example code) should be enough to get them. Good luck!

Comment: how do you know that they are deprecated? I've tried to google and didn't find any official documentation that would state that, anyway, thanks

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev You're quite welcome. Re: deprecated Rules and Defaults, why look at Google? Just look at the documentation that I linked for each one. There's a banner at the top of each page saying: "_**Important** This feature is in maintenance mode and may be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature._" Also see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms143729%28v%3dsql.100%29#features-not-supported-in-a-future-version-of-sql-server